# Check if multiple filename consist a specific string

Tags: bash

I am new to shell scripting and I can't figure it out on how to check the filenames if it has a specific string.

For example, the filenames are in `xyz.abc.d.CSV` format. How can I check if the filename contains that string?

Here is my code:

```
ls *.CSV | while read filename; do 
    if [ filename == "*abc*"]; then
        echo "Found it" 
    else
        echo "No abc"
done
```

ls *.CSV list all the files with a .csv format.
while reading the files, the code will compare if the filename have an "abc" string. if yes, the system will print "Found it", else, the system will print "No abc".

Comment: You can use grep command for that.

Comment: Why do you need this big loop for a simple grep statement? Check this ```ls *.CSV | grep -E "abc"```

Comment: Thank you @aicastell for your help :)

Comment: Thank you @AmitBhardwaj for your help :)

Comment: Use `echo *.CSV` instead of `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any loop. Just let the shell do the heavy lifting:

```
ls *abc*.CSV
```

Comment: @Aleeza please also remove the `ls` and `read` part. It's unnecessarily complicated and unsafe. Just `for filename in *abc*.CSV; do ...` will do.

Comment: At least for the purpose indicated in the question, `if ls *abc*.CSV > /dev/null; then` is probably the simplest thing to do. You don't actually care about the output, only the exit status, of `ls`. (Echoing the same, filename-agnostic string for each match seems pointless. Use the loop if there's actually something specific for each filename to do.)